# Creating a specular map using point lights?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

Im following a tutorial online (can't post it here its paid) and ive got myself stuck.

In the tutorial she says you need to create a secular map by making a black materiel then shining a point light and then baking the light information.

Hers looks something like this

[image]

[image]

I tried replicating the same effect, I have a Principled BSDF with black but I don't know how to bake it out so its just black and white. The only thing I can get working that exports the light information is Glossy but it leaves these purple and brown artifacts and I have no idea where its getting that.

Any help on how to fix this or get the same type of render results using a similar method?
[image]

Comment: Don't you think, as it is a paid course, that this girl should at least answer your question and guide you ?

Comment: Even tho its the same method shes using marmoset 3d to make and export the texture im using Blender

Answer (score 0):

I checked on youtube, and so far, I found this one :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PPTG1waeZ8

Comment: This is to import a spec map into blender. I need to make one using the highlights from the node